# Do pianos really need to rest before tuning, after being moved?

Tags: piano, tuning, maintenance

I'm new to real pianos and just having bought an old 2nd-hand one, it's obviously gone out of tune being moved to my house.

I've heard from a few people, including one tuner, that they need to 'rest' for a couple of weeks or even a month before tuning.

But the tuner I phoned today, who came highly recommended, said this was a myth unless the piano had moved between substantially different environments, and a few days was fine - in fact he said tuning the piano was the best way to *get* it 'settled in'.

So can anyone give a canonical answer about how long a piano should rest before tuning after a move?

Comment: In my specific case, it's an upright wooden-framed piano which was in decent tune before being moved. It moved about 10 miles from their living room to mine, and spent only about 30 min in transit in total.

Comment: I honestly don't think a 30 minute transit really counts as a move, do I  think you should have it tuned, but I'm no expert

Comment: It definitely needs tuning :)

Comment: I don't doubt that. I meant to tune it now. That you don't have to wait

Comment: Wood will expand and contract depending on the temperature and relative humidity of the environment it is in.  So moving a piano next door from my house to your house could easily result in movement of the wood parts due to difference in humidity/temperature.

Comment: I was just reading a whole article on this. Here: http://kansascitypianotuning.com/tuner/pianomovewaitmoving/

Comment: What do you mean by wooden-framed?  All pianos have a wooden case and a wooden soundboard.  But I'll bet there's an iron frame inside.  If it WAS wood-framed I'd expect an 1830 date rather than 1930.

Comment: The weather ten miles apart is likely to be pretty much similar. But the overall environment will be quite different if it moved from a poorly insulated hundred year old house with steam radiators and window air conditioners to a tightly insulted newish house with forced air heating and cooling.

Comment: Are you SURE it's a wooden frame?  That would be quite unusual.

Answer (score 15):

I am a Registered Piano Technician with the Piano Technicians Guild.

Pianos go out of tune during a move due to humidity differences and/or the different shape of the floor. The floor can slightly twist the piano which knocks it out.

Now, let's be reasonable here. Was this piano tuned every four months? Are you going to keep tuning it every four months? If the answer is yes, then you'll want to wait a few weeks.

If this piano is a typical 2nd hand piano, it has not been tuned in 10+ years and is quite far under pitch. The first tuning will not sound great so it's pointless to wait.

A good tuner will be able to get almost anything up to concert pitch. They will not be afraid of breaking strings because they know how to minimize the risk and they know how to replace strings. A piano at concert pitch is always preferred.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting and pragmatic answer Mark. In this particular case it is a pretty old piano - it says Wilbur so we think about 1930 - but the last 10-12 years was owned by the same guy, the head music teacher at a school who used it, taught his kids on it and had it tuned annually. When I inspected it, it was 9 months since the last tune but sounded pretty nice so I'm cautiously optimistic it's not _too_terrible :)

Comment: If the shape of the floor is pushing a piano out of tune you're looking at some serious structural issues.

Comment: Not structural issues. Professional piano technicians who are high level can hear the very small changes in pitch cause by the change in floor shape. Not everybody can hear this or cares.Btw an upright piano  should always have all four legs/wheels in full contact with the floor.

Answer (score 1):

I'd leave it for a week or so, as it's in a different environment - may be warmer, colder, more/less humid than its last home. Then get it tuned. You may have a nasty little surprise, especially if it's a wooden frame, when the tuner says he can't bring it back to concert pitch. Maybe he will over two or three tunings - maybe it doesn't matter to you, but if you want to play along with stuff, it's a real boon. Personally, I'm happy for my pianos to be right up at A=440Hz., as it's a perfect reference for other instruments, and it's how they should be, after all. The tuner may want to take a couple of goes anyway, depending on how far out it is. It's not unlike putting new strings on a guitar with vibrato - one thing affects another. Good luck!

Comment: Out of interest when a piano can't be brought to concert pitch, how much is it normally out? Like a few cents, or are we talking a semitone?

Comment: Heard some which were nearly a tone out. A plan, if yours won't come up, would be to have it a semitone down. Then at least you could play along to stuff. It'd teach you to play in other keys too!!

Comment: I'm hopeful it's OK. It was in tune (with itself) before moving and I played one key against my guitar and they were _very_ close. We'll see!

Comment: No pianos since about 1850 have a wooden frame if you’re talking about the plate. They’re all cast iron. 

They only reason a tuner would not tune a piano at concert pitch is that they or the customer don’t want to replace strings and there is a higher than normal chance of that happening due to current string condition. (Rust, preciously broken, repaired, or replaced strings.)

Comment: @MarkCerisanoRPT - reading the OP's comment, it seems to be a wooden frame.

Comment: Right. And I'm a registered piano technician and I'm telling you that not only do they not make wooden plates, but I have heard piano owners say their piano has a wooden frame more than I care to remember when they mean plate. All pianos DO have a wooden frame but the frame has NOTHING to do with withstanding the string tensions. It's all in the plate, the CAST IRON plate. Are you a piano technician? These answers should only be made by people with actual experience in my opinion. Sorry if I offend you.

Comment: @MarkCerisanoRPT- please correct me if I'm wrong - after all, it appears that you are the expert - but pianos that do not have  a cast iron frame that houses the strings, then they have a wooden frame.What I call (probably erroneously) the harp.I have met many pianos with those, and yes, they were old, and yes, pretty well unserviceable. I'm certainly not talking about any other wood structure. Don't blame me for what OP quotes! And, tuning every four months? Where did that come from? In my last studio there were three pianos (uprights), which were tuned every few years - all at concert pitch.

Answer (score 0):

There's not one right answer, and the biggest factor is the **humidity** change between origin and destination. 2 weeks is just fine in my experience, and after that the normal seasonal fluctuations in humidity will probably be as big as effect as any remaining acclimatization.

Answer (score 0):

I  am an experiênced  piano tuner  in Brasil.
If the  piano  during  the movie suffer  a heat  it nas to  wait  at  least  3 days. 
If  the piano  is moved  into  the  same  city, the same region nas in a truck  without  change  about  the clime  you  dont  have  tô wait  .